# redireccionar si no existe columna en base de datos

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, condiciones

Buen dia, tengo una tabla llamada empresa que tiene un campo llamado wizard en el cual se inserta "1" si el usuario ya completo su informacion y "0" si aun no la crea, pero se verifica mediante el id del usuario logueado, osea cada usuario tiene que tener una columna entonces si no existe la columna porque se acaba de registrar me arroja el error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2' in 'field list' (SQL: select `2` from `empresas` where `empresas`.`id` = adminid limit 1)
```

Se perfectamente que esto es porque no existe una columna en la tabla empresas con el id del usuario logueado, como podria filtrar si no existe el valor? o tendria que insertarlo al momento del registro? Cual es el error en mi middleware y mi controlador? espero puedan orientarme

DeniedController:

```
 $data=Empresa::where('adminid', Auth::user()->id)->first();// obtengo solo un registro el cual es un objeto, entonces ahora puedo hacer
        if ($data->wizard == 1) {
            return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'No tienes permiso de ingresar a esta ruta porque ya configuraste tu empresa');
          } elseif ($data->wizard == 0) {
            return view('admin.wizard');
          }
```

Middleware WizardVerification:

```
 $data=Empresa::where('adminid', Auth::user()->id)->first();// obtengo solo un registro el cual es un objeto, entonces ahora puedo hacer
          if($data->wizard == 0){
             return redirect('wizard');
          }
          return $next($request);
```

Comment: Como tienes configurada las rutas ? en `routes/web.php`  y la clases de `Empresa.php` , agrega esa información para que sea mas fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Intenta probar usando implícitamente `::where('adminid','=',Auth::user()->id)` , puedes ademas visualizar que SQL se esta generando agregando `->sql();` al final, esto retorna un string, esto para saber si el sql es correcto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No logro encontrar la relación entre el código que comentás y el error. El código va a fallar si es que no se encuentra una Empresa con el adminid igual al usuario logueado, tendrías que agregar ese caso

```php
$data = Empresa::where('adminid', Auth::user()->id)->first();
if($data === null) {
    // ... ¿qué pasa si la empresa es null?
}
if($data->wizard == 0){
    return redirect('wizard');
}
return $next($request);
```

Podrías comentar cuál es la linea de codigo donde falla?

Comment: Es importante validar el null, pero mira el SQL que contruye `select '2' from 'empresas' where 'empresas'.'id' = adminid` es como si los valores del `::where` pasaran inversos osea `user()->id` paso como la columna y `adminid` pasa como el valor.

Comment: tienes razon agregre al middleware como me comentas y funciona! redirecciona bien pero ahora me aparece el error "Trying to get property 'wizard' of non-object"

Comment: Esa misma validación la tenes que hacer en el controlador, y como comenta @DiegoMesa no queda muy claro de donde sale el `select  '2'...`

Comment: ya lo solucione, mi error era usar el controlador para la validacion y no el middleware, gracias a tu respuesta encontre que el error estaba en mi archivo de rutas donde le estaba indicando que usara el metodo index de un controlador para la verificacion, gracias a todos!